# cron script won't delete files?

Tags: debian, cron

I copied this from a blog entry, studied it, tweaked it a bit and more or less it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

GZ_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
GZ_TIME=`date +%H`

BK_PATH=/mnt/usbbk/sql
BK_FILE=$BK_PATH/$GZ_DATE-$GZ_TIME.gz

#
# Find all files older than 7 days (10080 minutes) and remove them
#

find BK_PATH* -type f -mmin +10080 -exec rm {} \;

#
# Dump and gzip export of SQL data
#

mysqldump --lock-all-tables --all-databases -u backup -p backup | gzip > $BK_FILE
```

However it does not seem to delete backups which are

Comment: I'm closing this as it's only about half a post... finish your post and I'll happily re-open it :-)

Comment: It does not delete backups which are what ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean to post this? It looks unfinished.

It's not deleting files because the line you would expect to delete them - the `find` command, which executes `rm` on the matching files it finds - is commented out (starts with a `#`). It's being ignored.

Comment: The last sentence seems to have been chopped. Weird. In any event, it was of little relevance.

It is commented out but even when it is not it still does not seem to delete dates backups? :s

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment `find BK_PATH* -type f -mmin +10080 -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the live version of this script, the find is not commented out (commenting a find -exec rm structure out in a pasted script is actually a good idea) ?

Comment: That would be correct this was done in error as I tested the script. I noticed just now the BK_PATH does not have the $ and no trailing slash is given. I changed that and now I will see what happens :)